# Dependant Select Components not showing the Selected Value in Input Field

Tags: reactjs, html-select

There are 4 select Components with dependant dropdown menu.But when I select an option its not displaying in the input field although my 'selectedPlanets' state is updating just right.

Here is my code -

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../css/Destination.css";

function Destination(props) {
  const [selectedPlanets, SetselectedPlanets] = useState([
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
  ]);

  const OnSelectPlanet = async (e, key) => {
    const clonedSelectedPlanets = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selectedPlanets));
    clonedSelectedPlanets[key] = e.target.value;
    SetselectedPlanets(clonedSelectedPlanets);
  };

  const CustomSelectComponents = ({ value, options, OnSelect}) => {
    return (
      <select value={value} onChange={OnSelect}>
        <option> -- Select a Planet -- </option>
        {options.map((option) => {
          return <option key = {option.name} value={option.name} >{option.name}</option>;
        })}
      </select>
    );
  };

  const OptionsToRender = (Alloptions, AllselectedOptions, index) => {
    console.log(AllselectedOptions);
    const optionstoRender =
      AllselectedOptions[index] != null
        ? Alloptions.filter(
            (option) =>
              !AllselectedOptions.some(
                (selectedOption) =>
                  option && selectedOption && option.name === selectedOption
              )
          )
        : Alloptions;
    return optionstoRender;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="Parent_Card">
        {selectedPlanets.map((planet, index) => {
          const options = OptionsToRender(props.planets, selectedPlanets, index);
          return (
            <>
            {console.log(index)}
            <CustomSelectComponents
              value={
                selectedPlanets[index] != null ? selectedPlanets[index] : ""
              }
              options={options}
              OnSelect={(e) => OnSelectPlanet(e, index)}
              key={index}
            />
            </>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Destination;
```

I tried debugging it and figured that its maybe because of how and when my component is rendering.But I dont know why and hence not able to find the solution.

My expected result is when I am choosing an option it shows in the input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could benefit from a few different approaches to building your 4 different select components:

- the use of controlled components
  (https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)
- separating the state for each of the different selects
- refactoring the `<CustomSelectComponent />` to be a component that only accepts props

Here is an example of those approaches in practice that might provide some direction on getting these selects operating as expected!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../css/Destination.css';

// custom select component
const CustomSelectComponent = ({ onChange, options, value }) => (
  <select onChange={onChange} value={value}>
    <option> -- Select a Planet -- </option>
    {options.map(option => (
      <option key={option.name} value={option.name}>
        {option.name}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
);

const Destination = () => {
  // mock props
  const props = { planets: [{ name: 'Pluto' }, { name: 'Earth' }] };
  // separated state
  const [selectOneValue, setSelectOneValue] = useState('');
  const [selectTwoValue, setSelectTwoValue] = useState('');
  const [selectThreeValue, setSelectThreeValue] = useState('');
  const [selectFourValue, setSelectFourValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <div className="Parent_Card">
      {/* each custom select component is now controlled by it's own state */}
      <CustomSelectComponent
        onChange={e => setSelectOneValue(e.target.value)}
        options={props.planets}
        value={selectOneValue}
      />
      <CustomSelectComponent
        onChange={e => setSelectTwoValue(e.target.value)}
        options={props.planets}
        value={selectTwoValue}
      />
      <CustomSelectComponent
        onChange={e => setSelectThreeValue(e.target.value)}
        options={props.planets}
        value={selectThreeValue}
      />
      <CustomSelectComponent
        onChange={e => setSelectFourValue(e.target.value)}
        options={props.planets}
        value={selectFourValue}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Destination;
```

Comment: This is one of the option but I really want to avoid duplicating code. I think there is some concept which I am not aware of is creating this problem

Comment: Your issue is then in the `filter` method of the `OptionsToRender` function which removes the selected option from available options within the dropdown. This results in the select receiving a value prop that is not an option. Inverting the logic should resolve the issue.

Comment: Or updating the logic to read `AllselectedOptions[index] === null` would also work.

Comment: Hi @proph3t, updating the logic to `AllselectedOptions[index] === null`  didn't exactly work as after selecting any option and clicking on the drop-down, all the options were still visible. What worked for me, was adding a separate Option component for the selected value. Thank you for your help.